# Proving that $x^{2^n} + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

> $x^{2^n} + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$.

I've been working on this and this is my process:
I would like to use Eisenstein's criterion so I considered the substitution $y=x-1$. So 
$$x^{2^n}+1=(y+1)^{2^n}+1=\sum_{k=0}^{2^n}{2^n \choose k}y^{2^n-k}+1$$
$$={2^n \choose 0}y^{2^n}+{2^n \choose 1}y^{2^n-1}+\ldots+{2^n \choose 2^{n}-1}y+2$$
Take $p=2$. Since $p$ doesn't divide $1=a_{2^n}$ and $p^2=4$ doesn't divide $2=a_0$ it only remains to show that  every ${2^n \choose j}$ for $1\leq j \leq 2^n-1$ is divisible by $2$ but I haven't succed showing the latter. Any ideas? Also, is my process correct? Thanks in advance

Comment: It is the [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) whose roots are the primitive roots of unity of order $2^{n+1}$. Those are irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Related question [Are these polynomials irreducible over $\Bbb Z$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714447/are-these-polynomials-irreducible-over-bbb-z) (part c))

Answer (score 3):

If you meant to say that $x^{2^n}+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then yes, it is indeed irreducible.  You are almost there with Eistenstein's Criterion approach.  To show that $\displaystyle\binom{2^n}{j}$ is even for $j=1,2,\ldots,2^n-1$, you may observe that
$$(y+1)^2\equiv y^2+1\pmod{2}\,.$$
Then, use induction on $n$ to verify that
$$(y+1)^{2^n}\equiv y^{2^n}+1\pmod{2}\,.$$